# How can I display all mail from one specific author in Mutt?

Tags: email, search, regex, mutt

I would like to display a search in mutt; i.e. all mails send by a specific author in inbox.

```
~f author
```

displays only the first mail from "author" surrounded by different mails. And I cannot navigate between the query results.

I would like a buffer with all mail from "author" (and only them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of *search*, you should use *limit*, which narrows the mailbox only to the matching messages.

This command is bound to <kbd>l</kbd> (lowercase L); so you'd type:

```
l
~f author
<RET>
```

Extra: in threaded mode, you can display complete threads where at least one of the messages are from *author*, with the following match expression:

```
~(~f author)
```